# Turning off oven breaker cuts power to AC, and vice versa. Why?

Tags: circuit-breaker, oven

Turning off oven breaker cuts power to AC, and vice versa.  Why?

Comment: Because it's wired wrong. But I suspect you already know that. A more helpful answer require more info from you, like some pics of how the breakers in your panel are wired.

Comment: Or they simply share the same breaker on the logic that if you are running the AC you probably won't be running the oven, and perhaps there was a shortage of breakers/spaces, in which case it's mostly a labelling problem if it's not labelled for both....

Comment: It sounds like the breakers are mislabeled in the panel.  It may be just a question of relabelling the breakers or it may be that the wires are wrongly connected. What is the amperage rating of the breaker labeled AC and what is the amperage rating of the one labelled oven?

Comment: Do you mean the "oven" breaker turns off power to the a/c and not to the oven?

Comment: What if they are merely mislabeled?  What is the ampacity of the breaker labeled "AC"?  What about the one labeled "range/oven"?  Ampacity is the number prominently listed on the handle.

Comment: Either breaker turns off the other with it, so power is off to both the AC and the oven.

Comment: They are separate breakers, but they are obviously connected.  Almost sounds like they are in series.

Comment: I've VTC because (not enough information) I'm going to have to assume you lack the expertise to *safely* provide us with the information we'd need to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood initially:  You have 2 breakers that both turn off the both devices.  This is consistent with two wires being swapped at the panel.

That is instead of

Stove Red => Stove
Stove Black => Stove
AC Red => AC
AC Black => AC

You may have

Stove Red => Stove
Stove Black => AC
AC Red => AC
AC Black = Stove

- Shut down power at the main breaker.
- tag the 4 wires in question so you can put them back.  Call them AR, AB, SR, and SB for Air conditioner, Stove, red, black.
- Turn the main breaker on
- Turn the stove breaker on, the AC off.
- Pull the stove from the wall and unplug the stove.
- Measure the difference between the neutral and each of the hot wires.  If one is hot, and the other is not, then TPE's hypothesis is supported.

Fixing it.

If the above is the case,

- go back to  the panel, turn the main off, remove one wire from the stove's breaker, cap it, turn the power back on.
- check the stove.  If the formerly hot wire is no longer hot, then the one you disconnected was the working wire.
- back to panel. Power off.  Reconnect working wire, disconnect other wire, cap it, power  on.
- back to stove. Now the setup should be exactly the same as when you first did this.  (I can't think of a reason how it could be different, but I tend to make redundant checks.)

If the AC actually plugs in, you can test it the same way, just to verify that the problem is what you think it is.

When you make this set of tests, be sure the stove breaker is back off.  I think it *should* be that the same leg is the connected one.  That is, if SR was the connected on when you did the stove test with the AC breaker on, then AR will be the connected one with the Stove breaker off.

If this is the case, then swap the two unconnected wires.  If you use the example above, SB and AB swap.

At this point:

- Turn stove breaker on, AC breaker off.
- Go check stove outlet.  You should now have two hot legs.
- Check AC outlet.  You should have two dead legs.
- Turn stove breaker off, AC breaker on.
- Stove outlet should now be dead
- AC outlet should now have two hot lines.
- Plug devices in. Turn both on.
- Verify that both work.

Note that all of this is based on the hypothesis that two legs of the breakers were reversed.  If, at some point, you get results that are incompatible with this hypotheses, it's time to stop, pour coffee, and rethink the whole process.

Note:  When I have done tests like this, I cap the loose wire if I'm going to turn the power back on.  This is probably paranoid, but I'm clumsy and easily distracted.  I don't really want to brush a hot wire because I got distracted.

As a sanity check (One mistake was made already...) Verify that neither devices has voltage floating around on exposed metal.  (I had a stove once that tried to kill me this way.)

I am NOT a professional Electrician.  This edit was an attempt to come up with a testing process for TPE's comment.

Comment: It sounds like the wires got crossed so that each breaker is feeding one leg of each circuit. (This could happen quite readily if the breaker was a quadplex, for instance)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have attempted to turn your comment into a checking procedure.  Please check it over.  I don't want to give bad advice.

Comment: The issue would be that the wrong wires are landed on the wrong breaker lugs, basically -- it sounds like you misunderstood my comment when you came up with the test procedure

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you've had this much response given the amount of information you've provided, like:

1. why is this a problem other than obviously miswired?  How did you discover it?
2. Are they tripping for some reason?
3. Is your AC a 120 wall unit, or a 240 HVAC system (HVAC can be 120 or 240 depending on whether you have electric heating coils etc).

That said, i'm going to take a stab at this and say that a) either they have been wired in series, or b) they are both 240 volt appliances and somehow share one leg of the 240V through a common wire routed to the breaker.

You could tell this by pulling off the panel cover and seeing if the wires trace to two distinct plastic-bundled runs (say of 12/3 or 10/3).  I think you'll have to visually determine this.  Be careful, don't die.